# Docker: unable to execute the mount command inside an ubuntu 16.10 container

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, docker, mount

My container images is derived from ubuntu 16.10

When container starts, it downloads an Android rom .zip image, then extract from it new system.new.dat and convert into an .img file (so it's now containing and ext4 partition)

```
system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, 
            UUID=57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b 
            (extents) (large files)
```

Then try to mount it (system is an actual empty but existing directory)

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop ./system.img /system
```

But I got this

```
mount: <path_to_>/system: mount failed: Unknown error -1
```

I'm not aware of the cause. What can I do to mount this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually resolved adding the `--privileged` switch at the `docker run` command